# Android Twitter OAuth that REALLY work?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

Any Example suggestion that really works currently with Twitter OAuth?
I just need a simple API to post from an Android App, no need for something fancy and full feature, something that just works fine for authentication, doesn't crash and can update status.

I tried at least 4 examples poested before, all of them fail at some point.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success with the [Twitter4J library](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). For my purposes the login credentials were hardcoded into my app though. It was not a situation where each user could log in to their own twitter account. But the library was very easy to use for retrieving statuses and posting a tweet.